# Stick image over bottom of other image

Tags: html, css, image, position, css-position

I want to position an svg image that I have over another image, but keep it at the bottom of the second image:

[image: What I want]

The image I want to stick at the bottom is the blue wavy one. I have got it to work, but it isn't responsive. So when I change the viewport, the blue image moves either up or down and doesn't cover the blurry image:

[image: What I have]

How can I make the blue image move with the blurry one?

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<div>
  <img
    src="https://i.imgur.com/Jqm7gPO.png"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"
  />
  <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; bottom: 10rem; width: 100%">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <path
        d="M0.00,49.99 C163.98,160.36 355.85,-98.19 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #4286ff;"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

The svg is the wavy image generated from here: https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `bottom: 10rem` is a hard-coded value that only works with a specific size of the outer div.

To make things more responsive, you can set the outer div's `position` to `relative`, the inner one's to `absolute`, and then set the inner div's `bottom` to 0. This makes the inner div always be at the very bottom of the outer one:

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <img
    src="https://i.imgur.com/Jqm7gPO.png"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"
  />
  <div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <path
        d="M0.00,49.99 C163.98,160.36 355.85,-98.19 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #4286ff;"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```